# Unable to pass namespace parameter to kubernetes-cli plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have couple of different contexts with namespaces defined within my k8s cluster.
Using different pipelines for Jenkins I'd like to switch between them.
Idea is: based on git branch to do a deployment to specific environment. In order to do that I'd have to switch to existing production/dev/feature contexts and namespaces.

I want to use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Cli+Plugin
This is an example syntax for Jenkins scripted piepline:

Example:

```
node {
  stage('List pods') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: '<credential-id>',
                    caCertificate: '<ca-certificate>',
                    serverUrl: '<api-server-address>',
                    contextName: '<context-name>',
                    clusterName: '<cluster-name>'
                    ]) {
      sh 'kubectl get pods'
    }
  }
}
```

And as you can see it does not accept anything for `namespace`

This is an example production context with namespace, which I'm using:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts 
CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER                           AUTHINFO                          NAMESPACE
*         aws-production   cluster.example.com   cluster.example.com       aws-production
```

And this is a result of running that step:
[image]

How to resolve that issue? Is it possible to use namespaces using mentioned plugin at all? If not is there an alternative way to achieve context+namespace switch during Jenkins pipeline step?

EDIT:
Seems that adding entry to .kube/config on Jenkins machine doesn't help for that issue. This plugin `kubernetes-cli` for Jenkins creates isolated context and does not care much about .kube/config :(

Manually forcing a config, doesn't help in this case too;

`kubectl config use-context aws-production --namespace=aws-production --kubeconfig=/home/jenkins/.kube/config`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to help from official Jenkins IRC channel, solution below.

Solution:
You have to pass raw .kube/config file as a `credentialsId`.

1. Create new creadentials in Jenkins. I have used Secret file option.
2. Upload you desired .kube/config and give it a name/id in credentials creation form.
3. Pass the id name you have given to this credential resource to `credentialsId` field

withKubeConfig([`credentialsId: 'file-aws-config'`, [..]]) ...

Answer (score 2):

The plugin doesn't have a `namespace` parameter but the `~/.kube/config` does. So you could create 2 contexts to handle the two different namespaces. In your ~/.kube/config`

```
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: k8s.mycluster
    namespace: mynamespace1
    user: k8s.user
  name: clusternamespace1
- context:
    cluster: k8s.mycluster
    namespace: mynamespace2
    user: k8s.user
  name: clusternamespace2
```

Comment: Right, we can set per-context/per-cluster/per-user `namespace` in kubeconfig: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

Comment: I know about that, that was next thing I was going to try - my only concern was that Jenkins runs on master and slave nodes and that would have to be added per node manually.

Comment: Seems that plugin kubernetes-cli with jenkins create separated/isolated instance of context, adding entry manually to .kube/config as you suggested works in out-of Jenkins scope (normal CLI).

Comment: Cool, looks like you found the other part of the solution